# When will Microsoft stop supporting SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

We are purchasing proprietary software that requires it run on a SQL Server 2005.  My concern is we will not be able to change/modify/enhance at all.  SQL Server 2005 is pretty old and want to know if you know when Microsoft will stop supporting this version.  Building my case not to purchase...

Comment: A simple solution would be to test it against SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=SQL)

SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition  4/12/2016

Also see [Service Pack Support](http://support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx?RDPATH=%2flifecycle%2fdefault.aspx#ServicePackSupport)

The **product** SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition stops being supported (in extended support mode) on 4/12/2016, but if you need a Service Pack other than the latest-released service pack, you will not have any support at all. During your support lifecycle you will need to keep on the latest service pack or risk losing support.